# Sticky footer in Salesforce 1 mobile app in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobile, custom-app

I am working on LWC and creating a custom app on Salesforce 1 App for mobile. I want to fix my footer component at the bottom of the mobile screen. I use this below code in html file.

By using this, its work on desktop but not in mobile:

[image]

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but you are aware that Salesforce1 experience is end-of-life? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349471&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1